# RoR - Workflow and Namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, workflow

I'm using Workflow in a Ruby on Rails application. Everything worked fine until I started moving Controllers into a namespace.

Now I get an "unknown action" error when I try to invoke events on the Model.

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'print_contract' could not be found for
>   Intern::TenanciesController

The first line of the Controller looks like this:

```
class Intern::TenanciesController < Intern::ApplicationController
```

It lies in app/controllers/intern/tenancies_controller.rb

The model that uses Workflow looks like this:

```
class Tenancy < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow
  workflow_column :state_id

  workflow do
    state :reserved do
      event :print_contract, :transitions_to => :warranted
    end
    state :warranted do
      event :sign, :transitions_to => :signed
    end
    state :signed do
      event :charge, :transitions_to => :charged
    end
    state :charged do
      event :admonish, :transitions_to => :inquiry
      event :demolished_stuff, :transitions_to => :inquiry
      event :pay, :transitions_to => :paid
    end
    state :inquiry do
      event :pay, :transitions_to => :paid
    end
    state :paid
  end

...
end
```

Routes are

```
  namespace :intern do
    resources :tenancies do
      member do
        get 'print_contract'
        get 'sign_contract'
        get 'charge'
        get 'pay'
      end
    end
  end
```

I couldn't find anything anywhere about using Workflow with namespaces. Is it even possible? If so, is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: provide more details: directory of the controllers, first line of your controller, routes you're using

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I still had to define the corresponding action in the TenanciesController. Not sure what made me think Workflow would magically do that.